# For Loops in Blogger, Replacing all characters in a string with the give character Java Script for Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

This is a simple question i have,

I have a simple script here :

```
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img').each(function(){
  var $img = $(this);
  var filename = $img.attr('src')
  var returnt=filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1,filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
  var returna=filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1,filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
  <b:loop values='returnt.length'>
    var ctitle=returnt.replace("%2B", " ");
    var calt=returna.replace("%2B", " ");
  </b:loop>
  $img.attr('title', ctitle);
  $img.attr('alt', calt);
  });
 });
//]]>
```

I wanted all the %2B in the **returnt** and **returna** to be replace with space and stored in **ctitle** and **calt** respectively, but without a loop it won't work.
I tried something like

```
for(int i=0;i<returnt.length;i++)
{
var ctitle=returnt.replace("%2B", " ");
var calt=returna.replace("%2B", " ");
}
```

But didn't work, now I have put the **values='returnt.length'** in the script but it's still not working. 
I know something is missing and is wrong somewhere, please tell me how to do it.

I want the loop to work like the given above for loop.

And I tried .replaceAll("","") method but didn't work. :(

**I want a method to replace all the characters or info on how to write the above for loop in blogger FOR LOOP method.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex matching in `replace`. The code will look like -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('img').each(function() {
 var $img = $(this);
 var filename = $img.attr('src')
 var returnt = filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
 var returna = filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/')) + 1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
 var ctitle = returnt.replace(/%2B/g," ");
 var calt = returna.replace(/%2B/g," ");
 $img.attr('title', ctitle);
 $img.attr('alt', calt);
});
});
```

The `b:loop` tag is native to Blogger platform. Its `values` attribute only accepts data tags present in Blogger and not custom JavaScript variables. Refer to the [documentation here](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995)

> The general format for using loops is this:
>
> ```
> <b:loop var='identifier' values='set-of-data'>   
> [repeated content goes here] 
> </b:loop>
> ```
>
> The 'identifier' (i) part can be any name you choose, and will be used
>   to stand in for each new item in the list, each time through the loop.
>   The set of data you specify for the values can be any piece of data
>   described in the [data tags article](http://web.archive.org/web/20161014105000/https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270) as being a list of items.